# Undefined symbol error when trying to mov into variable which defined in C code above assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, clion, inline-assembly

I am trying to run assembly code inside C code(on CLion). I defined variable x outside of assembly insert and tried to mov a number into it but compiler says x is undefined. I don't get how to make it see variables. Also I have to use intel syntax.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
short int x = 0;
__asm__ (
".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
"mov eax, 0x02\n\t"
"mov x, eax\n\t"
".att_syntax prefix\n\t"
);
printf("%d", x);
}
```

And there is error

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ass_lab_2.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ass_lab_2
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ass_lab_2.dir/main.cpp.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against undefined symbol `x' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

P.S. I solved problem. This [link](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/cc/13240-applying-c-assembler.html) was extremely helpful. You just need to pass your variables into **asm** function using it's syntax.

(Editor's note: the first couple pages of that, about using GNU C Basic asm statements to modify global variables, are unsafe (because there's no `"memory"` clobber) and only happen to work.  The only safe way to modify C variables is with Extended asm with input/output operands; later sections of that article cover that.)

Comment: It is the *linker* which cannot resolve `x`. Did you try its suggestion? "recompile with -fPIC"

Comment: What compiler and architecture are you compiling for?

Comment: Stupid of me I didn't try this. But now after reading some articles about recompiling with -fPIC I have no idea how to do this. I will try and tell later if it goes well.

Comment: `x` is defined as a `short`, which is inconsistent with `mov x,eax`

Comment: I am just compiling it in CLion on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Don't do this. Referencing variables inside assembly is not guaranteed to even work. The GCC inline assembly documentation has just such a warning. If you want to pass a memory address to a variable into inline assembly you need to use extended inline assembly syntax and a constraint. As well you can't just change registers (like EAX) without telling the compiler (extended inline assembly and clobbers can mitigate that)

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this at all, but an example that would work (although I wouldn't use a clobber) is this: https://godbolt.org/z/afbmhM . Rather than use `.intel_syntax noprefix`, add `-masm=intel` to your compiler options in CLION. This will change the default from AT&T syntax to Intel.

Comment: I think you have to use a constant in AT&T syntax -- `mov $0x02, %eax; mov (x), %eax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that `x` is a local variable. You will have to use [extended assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) to modify it (and use `-masm=intel` to use Intel syntax):

```
int main(void)
{
    short int x = 0;
    __asm__("mov %0, 0x02\n\t" : "=r"(x));
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Also, you can use AT&T syntax. It will look like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    short int x = 0;
    __asm__("mov $0x02, %0\n\t" : "=r"(x));
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Because I'm using the `=r` constraint here, this will be stored in a register; therefore, you don't need to use `eax` (which should be `ax`, by the way) as an intermediate storage place to store the value.

Comment: Note that switching to Intel-syntax and back for inline asm is a nasty hack that will break as soon as you want the compiler to substitute in an addressing mode like `dword ptr [rbp - 4]` for `"=rm" (x)` in debug mode.  It will still substitute `-4(%rbp)`.  And I think clang will break even for registers, if it rejects `%eax` in Intel-syntax mode (extraneous decoration).  The right way for GCC is to build with `-masm=intel`.  AFAIK there's no full workaround for clang.